# A second-order non-linear differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Which are the possible solutions for this second-order non-linear différential equation :

$$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial q} \frac{\partial^2 Z}{\partial p \space \partial t} -   \frac{\partial Z}{\partial p} \frac{\partial^2 Z}{\partial q \space \partial t} = 1$$

where $Z(p, q, t)$ is a real or complex function of the three real parameters $p, q, t$

Particular solutions are welcome, if no general solution can be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some particular solutions are given by
$$Z(p,q,t) = f(t)\left(q+p\int f(t)^{-2}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)+h(t),$$

for any differentiable $f(t)$ such that $\int f(t)^{-2}\,\mathrm{d}t$ exists and for any $h(t)$.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: A particular solution of your particular solution is : $Z(p,q,t) = - (q \space cos (\omega t) + \frac{p}{\omega} sin (\omega t))$

Comment: That's surprisingly nice.